# Center container and make width equal to its floated contents

Tags: html, css, css-float

This should be a basic css question, but as we all know sometimes it can be a tricky language.

```
<div id="main">    
    <div id="container">
        <div class="item">
        <div class="item">
        <div class="item">
        <div class="item">
        <div class="item">
        <div class="item">
    </div>
</div>

#main {clear: both; margin: 20px auto; max-width: 100%; width: 1000px;}
#container {clear: both; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 832px;}
.item {width: 208px; float: left;}
```

By default, there are 4 `.items` in a row. When I resize my browser window to smaller than 832px wide, the `.items` jump down to fit 3 in a row.

How do I center the 3 items within the `#container` or make the `#container` width equal to the width of its floated contents and center the `#container` in the `#main`?

[image: mockup]

Comment: Can you post a simple sketch or diagram of what you want the layout to look like?

Comment: Sure, just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is more or less what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/L3JVe/17/

It was a simple fix. I set your `.item`s to `display:inline-block;` and your `#container` to `text-align:center;`.

Your new CSS will look something like this:

```
#main {
    clear: both;
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
}

#container {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 832px;
    text-align:center; /*New*/
}

.item {
    width: 208px; /*May need to adjust*/
    display:inline-block; /*New*/
}​​​​​​​
```

Also, you'll need to remove all space between the items in the HTML to avoid space appearing between the rendered items. (Thanks, @thirtydot!)

Comment: This is close, but I can't have the gaps in between the items (which is why I floated them in my example)

Comment: @DaveKiss: In the HTML, remove the whitespace between the `div`s.

Comment: Right on, @thirtydot! @Dave Kiss, check out the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L3JVe/17/